Size of sda is much greater than sum of size of sub sda, but I can not extend or resize them
I'm trying to extend my hard disk, but it doesn't work correctly. According to many suggestions on the internet, I ran this command:
$ sudo lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs WWW-vg/root
  Size of logical volume WWW-vg/root unchanged from 47.52 GiB (12165 extents).
  Logical volume root successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem is already 12456960 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!

I also tried this command:
$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE WWW-vg/root
  New size (12165 extents) matches existing size (12165 extents)
  Run élvextend --help' for more information.

I'm sure, I've added the hard disk because when run lsblk, I'll get this output:
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  110G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0  487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2               8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5               8:5    0 49.5G  0 part 
  ├─WWW--vg-root   252:0    0 47.5G  0 lvm  /
  └─WWW--vg-swap_1 252:1    0    2G  0 lvm  ÄSWAPÅ
sr0                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  

It's confusing to me why the size of the sda is 110G but the sum of sda1,sda2,sda5 is 50G. Where is another 60G? How can I add this 60G to my WWW--vg-root?
Here's some information about my device that I hope they help.
$ lvs -o +devices
  LV     VG     Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices         
  root   WWW-vg -wi-ao---- 47.52g                                                     /dev/sda5(0)    
  swap_1 WWW-vg -wi-ao----  2.00g   

$ df -h
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                      979M     0  979M   0% /dev
tmpfs                     200M  5.9M  195M   3% /run
/dev/mapper/WWW--vg-root   47G   17G   29G  37% /
tmpfs                    1000M     0 1000M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                    1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                 472M  110M  338M  25% /boot
tmpfs                     200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000

$ pvdisplay -m
--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               WWW-vg
  PV Size               49.52 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12677
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12677
  PV UUID               Xukces-Bzjn-Sqkk-klvc-wm6I-FwfM-bFuzjx
   
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 12164:
    Logical volume  /dev/WWW-vg/root
    Logical extents 0 to 12164
  Physical extent 12165 to 12676:
    Logical volume  /dev/WWW-vg/swap_1
    Logical extents 0 to 511

$ fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 110 GiB, 118111600640 bytes, 230686720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x399c3ae0

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048    999423    997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 104855551 103854082 49.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 104855551 103854080 49.5G 8e Linux LVM




Disk /dev/mapper/WWW--vg-root: 47.5 GiB, 51023708160 bytes, 99655680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/WWW--vg-swap_1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

And this is my ubuntu version
Ubuntu 16.04.07 LTS


Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

sda5 is a logical partition and resides inside the extnded partition sda2. Try to resize the extended partition sda2 first. You may also need to resize sda5 then`. Then resize your LVM-volume. Or create a primary parttition in the empty space and add it to your volume group.

How? with resize2fs? I ran resize2fs /dev/sda2 60G but It doesn't work. resize2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sda2 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.  @mook765

You should boot from another drive, not from the drive where you want to edit the partition table. I suggest that you boot from a live Ubuntu system on a USB drive. And I suggest that you download and use a current version of Ubuntu for that purpose, for example 24.04.1 LTS, which is the newest long term support version. And you should replace your Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS version with the current version 24.04.1 LTS (after testing that it works with your computer).

resize2fs is a tool to resize filesystems, not partitions. Please see https://askubuntu.com/a/18525/590937

@guiverc in this case, the version of Ubuntu is completely irrelevant though. Is there really any benefit to the site in closing this question when the exact same question is 100% applicable to newer versions as well?

Ali, if this is closed, please ask on [unix.se] instead. The answer is that you need to extend the partition that holds the LVM, you can't resize the LVVM because that is already ay 100% of the partition that contains it. But please do ask so you can get a proper answer with the relevant commands and explanation.

@sudodus That's a lot to do :( but according to other comments, it seems there is no other option. tnx for participating in this question

Thanks for your attention @terdon, I'm gonna try booting from another drive and edit the partition table. I think it will work
